# WSO2DSS 3.5.1 - Issue in JSON response from a RESTful service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have defined a restful service with nested queries. Output mapping is defined in XML. I get proper response as XML. But if I request a JSON response using Accept:Application/json I get

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "faultcode": "soapenv:Server",
    "faultstring": "Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter",
    "detail": ""
  }
}
```

I was getting below exception in 3.5.0 and I found a jira saying it is fixed in 3.5.1. So I tried in 3.5.1 now I am not getting below exception but the same output.

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid Staring element
```

Please note I have also tried the `escapeNonPrintableChar="true"` option in my queries but no use. Strange thing is it working for different data sets. Just one particular data set is throwing this output.

I have changed the JSON formatters as below and got it to work but there is a problem in that.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonFormatter" / -->

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonBuilder" /-->
```

If I use above formatter the null values are not represented properly. Like I get

```
"Person": {
          "Name": {
            "@nil": "true"
          }
```

but I want it as (like the other JSON formatter used to give)

```
"Person": {
          "Name": null
          }
```

Any help please. Is there a bug still left in this area?

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating the query in your output response, you define the format you want to receive the response you can select xml or json, in the case you mention you can select the json option, then select generate response this creates this json structure.

```
{
 "entries": {
 "entry": [
 {
 "field1": "$column1",
 "field2": "$column2"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

Then you can modify the answer you need with your fields. Here is an example of how I use it in my query

```
{
 "Pharmacies": {
 "Pharmacy": [
 {
 "ID": "$Id",
 "Descripcion": "$Desc",
 "Latitude": "$Latitude",
 "Longitude": "$Longitude",
 "Image": "$Image"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

The values ​​with "$" are correspond to the name of the column of the query

Regards